# How to set var self = this; from outside the function?

Tags: javascript

I have a class-like function

```
var myapp = function() {
    this.method = function() {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

To reference `myapp` from within methods, the first line in the `myapp` function is

```
var self = this;
```

So a method in `myapp` can reference the "class" safely

```
this.anothermethod = function() {
    self.method();
}
```

The full code:

```
var myapp = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.dosomething = function(Callback) {
        Callback();
    }

    this.anothermethod = function() {
        //Pass a callback ("self" is required here)...
        this.dosomething(function() { 
            self.complete(); 
        )};
    }

    this.complete = function() {
        console.log('All done!');
    }
}
```

**My question is**: can I assign `var self = this;` from *outside* the declaration of `myapp`? I don't want to set `self` every single time I write a "class".

Kind of like this:

```
var library = function() {
    this.loadclass = function(Name) {
        var tempclass = window[Name];

        library[Name] = new tempclass();

        library[Name].self = library[Name];
    }
}

var myapp = new library();

myapp.loadclass('myapp');

myapp.myapp.dosomething();
```

It doesn't work as expected. `self` equals `window` for some reason.

I know it's a little abnormal programming, but can it be done?

---

Note about using `self`: I remember why I started using it. I wanted to reference the base class (`this`) from within callbacks inside methods. As soon as you try to use `this` within a function within a method, it then references the method, not the base class.

Comment: Why are you assigning methods on `this` in the constructor instead of setting them on the prototype?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Not even necessary. It depends on how `anothermethod` is called. If called as `myapp_instance.anothermethod();` then you can omit the whole `self` stuff.

Comment: I've updated the last example to use the previous examples. It now shows how I'm actually using it.

Comment: The following code goes outside the body of `myapp` to declare the method `anothermethod` through the prototype: `myapp.prototype.anothermethod = function() {this.method();};`

Comment: I remember now why I started using `self`: I had functions within methods that needed to reference the base one, such as for callbacks.

Comment: Regarding your edit; in the line `library[Name] = new class();` you are using an object as if it was a constructor function. The variable `class` references an instance of `library`, not the function `library`.

Comment: @Guffa I think I understand a lot about classes and constructors, but what you said went over my head. Edit: Oh I think you're talking about actually using the keyword `class`. I've edited the example to remove any mention of the keyword.

Comment: No, it's not the keyword `class` that is the issue that I was talking about. You are calling the `loadclass` method with the string `'myapp'`, so `tempclass` will be `window['myapp']`, i.e. the global variable `myapp`. You created an instance of `library` and assigned to `myapp`, so `tempclass` will point to that object. You can't use the `new` keyword on an object, only a function.

Comment: `window['myapp']` is a global function, not an object though. When I use `new` on `window['myapp']` it hasn't been instantiated yet. I'm basing this on the fact that the code actually works, it's just the `library['myapp'].self` isn't set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't really; not the way you're creating objects at least.

You can sort of do this, by enumerating all the functions on the object and binding them to the object itself. Something like this:

```
Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(function(n) { return typeof obj[n] == "function" })
  .forEach(function(n) { obj[n] = obj[n].bind(obj) })
```

This function will go over the public, enumerable properties of `obj` and make sure that any functions on it are bound to `obj`; i.e. `this` is now bound to `obj`.

---

### A primer on `this`

When you call new, `this` within the constructor gets bound to the newly created object. If you do need a reference to `this` as it was bound at constructor time, you do need to keep away a reference to it.

Functions in JavaScript are bound to wherever it is called. Here's an example:

```
var foo = new function() {
  this.bar = function() {
    return 'bar'
  }

  this.baz = function() {
    return this.bar()
  }
}

console.log(foo.bar()) // bar
console.log(foo.baz()) // bar

var bar = function() {
  return "window"
}

var baz = foo.baz

console.log(baz()) // window
```

When we call `foo.baz()` it'll look to `foo` for the implementation of `bar`, but when calling `foo.baz` through a "detached" reference, it'll look to whatever the global object is (in this case the browser window object) and call `bar` from there. Because we defined `bar` in the global context, it then returns `window`.

The practice of assign a variable called `self` is so that it doesn't matter how you call your methods, because you always reference the `this` at the time of creation through the `self` variable. You don't have to write things this way, but then you should understand that references to `this` may change under your feet.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up why I was getting that result when trying to assign `self` in the last example!

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: It explains why I was getting the result that I'm currently getting, not how I can programmatically set `self` when instantiating my fake class. Or you could actually have answered it and I'm just getting caught up in the massing number of comments and answers. :s

Comment: Well, I did answer it: you can't, not the way you're creating these classes. There is a way to sorta kinda do it, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Actually yes, now that I think about it. This isn't the type of thing one should be asking the first thing in the morning! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are detaching the methods from the object and calling them as plain functions, you don't need a `self` variable at all. The method can reach its object using the `this` keyword:

```
var myapp = function() {

  this.method = function() {
    //Do something...
  }

  this.anothermethod = function() {
    this.method();
  }

}
```

Comment: Might wan't to clarify that "detaching the methods" means calling them without `myapp.`; I have a feeling the OP might get confused otherwise.

Comment: I don't think I've ever actually tried doing it without `self`. I've always thought `this` was affected by scope, so `this.method()` would error out because it hasn't been declared.

Comment: @Jazza: `this` is bound to where it is called, so on an instance it would be `instance.anothermethod`, where `this === instance` insite `anothermethod` in Guffa's version of it.

Comment: @Jazza: It wasn't declared when you used it in `var self = this;` either. Whenever you call a method with the syntax `foo.bar()`, `this` is set to `foo` in the scope of the `bar` call.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah I just remembered why I started using `self`. I commented why on the OP.